# Show that $a=c\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\beta}+b\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\gamma}$ in a triangle $ABC$ with side lengths $a$, $b$ and $c$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

The question goes like this:

> In triangle $ABC$, the lengths of the sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ are $a$, $b$, $c$ respectively, and the radian measures of the angles at $A$, $B$, $C$ are $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ respectively. Prove that
> $$a=c\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\beta}+b\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\gamma}.$$

**My attempt at a solution:**
[image]

For convenience sake, let $z^{}_1$, $z^{}_2$ and $z^{}_3$ denote the complex numbers represented by the points $A$, $B$ and $C$ respectively in an Argand diagram.

Referring to my drawing above, since $\overrightarrow{CB}$ is $\overrightarrow{CA}$ stretched by a factor of $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and rotated through $\gamma$ radians anticlockwise (about $C$), I conclude that
$$z_2-z_3=\frac{a}{b}e^{i\gamma}(z_1-z_3).$$

Using similar arguments for the directed line segment pairs $\overrightarrow{BC}, \overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{AB}, \overrightarrow{AC}$, I obtain
$$z_1-z_2=\frac{c}{a}e^{i\beta}(z_3-z_2), \quad z_3-z_1=\frac{b}{c}e^{i\alpha}(z_2-z_1).$$

How do I proceed from here onwards to establish the given result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally with problems like this, you want to pick a nice coordinate system which makes the calculations become as trivial as possible.  In this case, let's pick coordinates so that $B=0$, $C$ is on the positive real axis, and $A$ is in the upper half plane.  This means that as a complex number, $C$ is just $a$.  Travelling from $B$ to $A$, we find that $A=ce^{i\beta}$.  On the other hand, travelling instead from $C$ to $A$, we get $A=a+be^{i(\pi-\gamma)}=a-be^{-i\gamma}$.  Setting these two expressions for $A$ equal gives the desired equation.

Answer (score 1):

By cosine rule we can prove $$b\cos \gamma+c\cos \beta=a$$
Also by sine rule:$$c\sin \beta-b\sin \gamma=0$$
Thius $$a=b\cos \gamma+c\cos \beta+i(c\sin \beta-b\sin \gamma)$$
$$a=ce^{i\beta}+be^{-i\gamma}$$

Comment: Seems more trivial than what I expected, thanks haha